# Migrate from claims-based authentication to classic-mode sharepoint 2010

Tags: migration, authentication, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

We are planning to change the authentication provider from claims-based authentication to classic windows mode. I am planning to do this by preserving the content databases and re-create the web-app with the new authentication. Can anyone tell me how to migrate the users to the new authentication i.e. relinking them with the previous identities on security groups and/or their documents? Any suggestion to do this in a better way would be great as well.

Comment: how did you get this fixed?? i need the answer badly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command in PowerShell under a SPWeb object called MigrateUsers. But tbh im not sure if it works the other way, setting it true converts users from classic to claims. One should think setting to false would do the opposite. But I haven't tested it.

Using the Move-SPUser command with a powershell script should do the trick.

Something like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/03/12/migrate-users-from-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2007-to-sharepoint-2010-fba-claim-based-authentication.aspx)

Comment: I know that the migrateUsers command doesnt work the other way. Thanks for the link, I might be able to extract something out of it and make it work.

Comment: Here is a link to a script that go from claims to classic: http://sharepointegg.blogspot.com/2011/01/reverting-claim-based-authentication-to.html

Comment: Yoohoo! This guy is a rockstar! And so are you! Thanks you!